# Problem with Spring Batch reader from PostgreSQL DB1 to write in PostgreSQL DB2

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-batch

I have a problem when I want to read data from PostgreSQL Author DB and write to the PostgreSQL Book DB.
I create configurations for the two DB and this is work well. 
My problem is in ItemReader.
 This is my error:

`Encountered an error executing step ETL-file-load in job ETL-Load`
error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: author is not mapped [select id,firstname,lastname from author]`

This is my `SpringBatchConfig` configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchConfig {

     @Autowired
      private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

     @Bean
        public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                       StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                       ItemReader<Author> itemReader,
                       ItemProcessor<Author, Book> itemProcessor,
                       ItemWriter<Book> itemWriter
        ) {

            Step step = stepBuilderFactory.get("ETL-file-load")
                    .<Author, Book>chunk(100)
                    .reader(itemReader)
                    .processor(itemProcessor)
                    .writer(itemWriter)
                    .build();


            return jobBuilderFactory.get("ETL-Load")
                    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                    .start(step)
                    .build();
        }

     @Bean
        public ItemReader<Author> itemReader() throws Exception {
            JpaPagingItemReader<Author> reader = new JpaPagingItemReader<Author>();
            reader.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
                        reader.setQueryString("select id,firstname,lastname from author");

            reader.setPageSize(5);
            reader.afterPropertiesSet();

            return reader;
        }

}
```

This is my `Processor` class:

```
@Component
public class Processor implements ItemProcessor<Author, Book> {

@Override
public Book process(Author item) throws Exception {

    Book book = new Book();
    book.setName(item.getFirstname());

    return book;
}
```

}

This is my DBWriter Class:

```
   @Component
public class DBWriter implements ItemWriter<Book> {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Book> book) throws Exception {
         System.out.println("Data Saved for Users: " + book);
            bookRepository.save(book);

    }
```

}

This is my Author JPA:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1848119459950659679L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastname;
```

This is my application.properties file:

```
spring.postgresql.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/book_db
spring.postgresql.datasource.username=admin
spring.postgresql.datasource.password=admin
spring.postgresql.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver


# ------------------------------
# POSTGRESQL DATABASE 2 CONFIGURATION
# ------------------------------
spring.mysql.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/author_db
spring.mysql.datasource.username=admin
spring.mysql.datasource.password=admin
spring.mysql.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

This is Auhtor in DB:
[image]

This is my full output:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: author is not mapped [select id,firstname,lastname from author]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1679) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:294) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader.createQuery(JpaPagingItemReader.java:112) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader.doReadPage(JpaPagingItemReader.java:203) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractPagingItemReader.doRead(AbstractPagingItemReader.java:108) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:88) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:157) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:116) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:110) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:392) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) [spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) [spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:216) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:233) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:125) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:119) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:784) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:771) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at com.roufid.tutorial.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: author is not mapped [select id,firstname,lastname from author]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: author is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:321) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3687) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3576) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:716) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:572) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:309) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    ... 70 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace. Are you sure `Author` is correctly declared as an Entity in the JPA config?

Comment: Sorry, I edit my post and know you can see everting about Author table and output error.

Comment: I am guessing there is an issue with name of table in your DB - it might be possible you might have table name which starts with uppercase "Author" and in you JPA query you are trying to refer it with lowercase e.g. "author"

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not a valid JPA Query.

This would be a valid query:

```
select a.id, a.firstname, a.lastname from Author a
```

BUT you want to select the whole Author so it must be

```
select a from Author a
```

Comment: I changed the query and I got this error: 
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Author is not mapped [select a.id, a.firstname, a.lastname from Author a]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your problem is solved, but I found the solution.

```
"select id,firstname,lastname from author"
```

replace

```
"from id,firstname,lastname from author"
```